# Running QuickTime 7 Pro on post-Mojave macOS

Tags: video, quicktime, subtitle

I have a number of old video files and will likely continue to receive new ones that contain QuickTime 7 Pro TextTracks as subtitles and would like to find a future-proof way of being able to access the TextTrack data. This was all part of an old research workflow that added multiple TextTracks to each QuickTime video. I'm currently still running Mojave, since it is the last OS supporting QuickTime 7, but I need urgently to update to the latest macOS for different reasons.
It's not really feasible to go through each video prior to updating and extract the TextTrack with QuickTime 7 so I'd be able to convert to subrip or whatever other format. I will also likely be receiving in the future new files in this format from other researchers and collaborators who had been using this workflow.

Is there any way to access the TextTracks after updating macOS to Catalina and later versions?

Is there any program who would still be able to read these files (at least extract the TextTrack text plus timecode, even if it doesn't play the video)?  (I'm not talking about textfiles in the QT format, which would be a no-brainer, but about .mov or .mp4 files that have a QT formatted TextTrack which currently can only be seen in QuickTime 7 Pro)

Alternatively, has anyone tried installing QuickTime 7 in a [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) emulator? Any ideas if this might work?

Comment: I don't know QuickTime TextTrack, but have you tried [VLC](https://www.videolan.org), which is pretty much a Swiss Army knife for video?

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately VLC doesn't recognize QT TextTracks.